# PostGIS "union" like in ArcGIS

Tags: postgis, arcmap

Is there a solution in postgis that will allow me to "union" two shapes / sets of shapes, where the output is unmerged?  That is to say, it should flatten the inputs, but maintain any lines / splits / polygon boundaries in the output.  Essentially I'd like it to work like the union tool in ArcMap.  The true union in postgis merges the outputs.  Any thoughts appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers. It is necessary you show some code for others to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ST_Intersection](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html):

```
SELECT distinct ST_Intersection(t1.geom,t2.geom) as geom
FROM test_polygon AS t1 CROSS JOIN test_polygon AS t2;
```

Comment: this will only capture the intersect. The union in arcgis is intersect + symmetrical difference